# Combining downloaded GESDISC timeseries precipitation data using xarray with weird naming file

Tags: python-xarray

I downloaded a subset of precipitation data from 2000 up to 2020 using NASA's GESDISC and got the file I wanted when i checked in panoply and/or QGIS.

I am having trouble in reading the file using python (xarray), can anyone help me ?, i will leave 5 days of example files in the link below, thanks a lot!

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14YPbE2CtZatEqD2gvoky-kUQSeCd-ACT?usp=drive_link

Comment: I can open the file `3B-DAY.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20000601-S000000-E235959.V07.nc4.nc4@precipitation[0 0][2964 2974][885 894],time,lon[2964 2974],lat[885 894]` without problem, what's your error ?

Comment: ----> 3 from ._netCDF4 import *
      4 # Need explicit imports for names beginning with underscores
      5 from ._netCDF4 import __doc__

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _netCDF4: The specified procedure could not be found.

This is mainly my problem, I have checked the dependencies are up to date and I tried to clean the naming of the file but having issues using python, now I'm trying using R and it's working smoothly, thank you for your time to look at my problem, have a good day :)